# Get specific values in Woocommerce Rest API

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, rest-api

If I used /wp-json/wc/v3/products I am getting all products, but what if I want to receive only price and quantity, I searched all we web and couldn't find it!

Answer (score 5):

Woocommerce rest API is an extension of WordPress rest API, so you should first check global parameters and specifically "_fields" in the [REST API Handbook of Wordpress.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/global-parameters/#_fields).

I will give you an example of the data that you want, price and quantity, but also the id and the name of the products for the response to be more human friendly.

```
/wp-json/wc/v3/products?per_page=100&_fields=id,name,regular_price,stock_quantity
```

> The "_fields" attribute is used for every attribute you want to get.
>
> The "per_page" attribute with value of "100" is used to get 100
> products which is the max acceptable value of this attribute and if
> you leave it empty the default is only "10".

Sorry for the 10 months later answer, but I hope that helped you and any other that is facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, sorry for my bad english!

In PHP, after your file_get_contents(home_url().'/wp-json/wc/v3/products'), use json_decode and get your informations like this:

```
<?php
    $products = json_decode(file_get_contents(home_url().'/wp-json/wc/v3/products'));
    foreach($products as $product){

        echo $product->price;
        echo $product->regular_price;
        echo $product->sale_price;
        
        echo $product->stock_quantity;
    }
?>
```

You can put a look here for more informations: https://woocommerce.github.io/woocommerce-rest-api-docs/#products

EDIT:
If you want stock the price and quantity only with the product, you can do this:

```
<?php
    $products = json_decode(file_get_contents(home_url().'/wp-json/wc/v3/products'));
    
    $products_array = array();
    foreach($products as $product){
        
        $products_array[] = array(
            'id' => $product->id,
            'price' => $product->price,
            'stock_qty' => $product->stock_quantity,
        );
    }
?>
```

use or return $products_array...

Comment: There is no magic link to directly retrieve only the desired data